# Downloading watchOS app container from a real device

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watchos

Is there a way to download an app container for a watchOS app running on a real device?

PS: for an iOS app, the one can use Xcode Devices and Simulators window, but there only iOS apps are listed and there is no way to check the apps installed on Apple Watch.